# Android Accesibility Service

Tags: android, accessibility

Can anyone explain me suppose I have an Accessibility Service defined by my application. It starts running when the Accesibility permission is given to the App. Suppose due to some reason memory issues the service is stopped. How can I make the Service start again cannot find any way to do it. Please help.

Thank u very much.

Hi Oblivion, I am new to asking questions untill today i used to just refer Stack Overflow :-) . Sorry I ll make sure I ll be putting the complete description. Now my problem.

I am thinking of two approaches

1. Start as Sticky service
2. Run the Service in a different process

first approach -> Suppose the app crashes and due to the fact it is sticky it restarts and due to some bug of previous crash it crashes again with some exception after that Android will not start the service
Posible Soln -> Make the Service logic as much error free as possible

second approach -> Run the Service in a different process as http://mindtherobot.com/blog/37/android-architecture-tutorial-developing-an-app-with-a-background-service-using-ipc/ 
and make sure you take all the solutions mentioned for first approach.

All these things I have done and it is solving my problem.

My original question is suppose I have bound a client to the Accesibility service and I have come to know that my Accesibility service is not running, is there a way by which I can fire an intent and tell Android to start my AccesibilityService.
I need to do this because I want to control the lifecycle of my Accesibilityand not Android.

Comment: post your code, and share where you are having trouble, that's the way to ask a complete question

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Please check out the help (http://stackoverflow.com/help) secion before posting any Questions on SO. Thanks.

Comment: Simple way of starting a service startService(new Intent(this, YourService.class)); which tells android to start service. Similarly somehow I know that my AccesibilityService is no longer running, I dont want my user to go to Settings-> Accesibilty to restart the Service

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
Toast.makeText(this, "service starting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

//your code!!!

// If we get killed, after returning from here, restart
return START_STICKY;
}
```

Change your `return statement` like above. It will restart your service again.

**START_NOT_STICKY**

If the system kills the service after onStartCommand() returns, do not recreate the service, unless there are pending intents to deliver. This is the safest option to avoid running your service when not necessary and when your application can simply restart any unfinished jobs.

**START_STICKY**

If the system kills the service after onStartCommand() returns, recreate the service and call onStartCommand(), but do not redeliver the last intent. Instead, the system calls onStartCommand() with a null intent, unless there were pending intents to start the service, in which case, those intents are delivered. This is suitable for media players (or similar services) that are not executing commands, but running indefinitely and waiting for a job.

**START_REDELIVER_INTENT**

If the system kills the service after onStartCommand() returns, recreate the service and call onStartCommand() with the last intent that was delivered to the service. Any pending intents are delivered in turn. This is suitable for services that are actively performing a job that should be immediately resumed, such as downloading a file.

we can return any of above, depends on our requirement.

Source:[Here!!!](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)

Comment: Now i added source, thanx for this! @rmtheis

Comment: Thank you rmtheis & Baratam....I have followed all ur posts here in Stackoverflow and it has worked for me perfectly.

Comment: Simple way of starting a service startService(new Intent(this, YourService.class)); which tells android to start service. Similarly somehow I know that my AccesibilityService is no longer running, I dont want my user to go to Settings-> Accesibilty to restart the Servic